Trouble with flutter dependency management
I'm new on Flutter and i'm having some doubt about how i'm managing dependencies.
Here's my current dependencies on the pubspec.yml:
environment:
   sdk: '>=3.4.1 <4.0.0'


dependencies:
   flutter:
      sdk: flutter


   cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
   english_words: ^4.0.0
   supabase_flutter: ^2.5.8
   intl: ^0.19.0
   collection: ^1.18.0
   flutter_svg: ^2.0.10+1
   timezone: ^0.9.4
   modal_bottom_sheet: ^3.0.0
   excel: ^4.0.3
   file_picker: ^8.0.6
   universal_io: ^2.2.2
   flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.13.1"
   url_launcher: ^6.3.0
   envied: ^0.5.4+1
   envied_generator: ^0.5.4+1
   build_runner: ^2.4.11
   version: ^3.0.2
   package_info_plus: ^8.0.0
   http: ^1.2.1

on pub get i have the following output:
Resolving dependencies...
Downloading packages...
  _fe_analyzer_shared 67.0.0 (73.0.0 available)
  analyzer 6.4.1 (6.8.0 available)
  archive 3.4.9 (3.6.1 available)
  collection 1.18.0 (1.19.0 available)
  http_parser 4.0.2 (4.1.0 available)
  leak_tracker 10.0.4 (10.0.5 available)
  leak_tracker_flutter_testing 3.0.3 (3.0.5 available)
  material_color_utilities 0.8.0 (0.12.0 available)
  meta 1.12.0 (1.15.0 available)
  rxdart 0.27.7 (0.28.0 available)
  shelf 1.4.1 (1.4.2 available)
  string_scanner 1.2.0 (1.3.0 available)
  test_api 0.7.0 (0.7.3 available)
  web 0.5.1 (1.0.0 available)
  web_socket_channel 2.4.5 (3.0.1 available)
Got dependencies!
15 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.
exit code 0

And i can't upgrade collection to version ^1.19.0 because i get this error:
Resolving dependencies...
Note: collection is pinned to version 1.18.0 by flutter_test from the flutter SDK.
See https://dart.dev/go/sdk-version-pinning for details.


Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on collection 1.18.0 and *** depends on collection ^1.19.0, flutter_test from sdk is forbidden.
So, because *** depends on flutter_test from sdk, version solving failed.


You can try the following suggestion to make the pubspec resolve:
* Consider downgrading your constraint on collection: flutter pub add collection:^1.18.0

What can i do to solve somehow this situation? What am i missing?
Thanks in advance!!

As explained in the link in the error message ( https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/main/docs/Flutter-Pinned-Packages.md ) Flutter 'pins' a handful of packages to specific versions. If you want to use one of those packages, you must use exactly that version (in this case collection 1.18.0). You cannot move to 1.19.0 until Flutter moves its pin up.

Thanks! I was wondering if it is the same for packages like analyser, web ecc... as shown in the second code snippet.

This behavior is currently (July 2024) as expected.
Yes, I know it's annoying. It seems for the longest time, Flutter has pinned collection to one minor revision below the latest, resulting in output like this from flutter pub outdated:
Package Name   Current  Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest  

direct dependencies:
collection     *1.18.0  *1.18.0     *1.18.0     1.19.0  

But clearly, that output says that the latest resolvable (NOT the latest available) is 1.18.0.
I don't understand why, if collection is using Semantic Versioning (I don't know whether it is or not), it should be pinned like this (=1.18.0), rather than pinned to a major version (^1.18.0, which would allow 1.19.0, 1.20.0, etc.). Hopefully they will address this in the future.
Until then, unfortunately we have to pin to the version that Flutter supports, hence two things to keep in mind:

If you build any Dart packages that you or others will depend on, avoid requiring the very latest minor version of collection.

You can easily add collection using dart pub add collection, and it will automatically choose the correct version annotation in pubspec.yaml.



Ok many thanks!! But is it the case also for the packages shown in second code snippet?
